# What does '=?' mean in the scope of a directive in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I have the following code and in that, codeValue property is set to '=?'. Please note the question mark after the equal to symbol.

What does '=?' do?

```
app.directive('questionMark', function () {  
   return {  
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {  
         codeValue: "=?"  
      },  
      template: 'Hello world'  
   };  
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> All 4 kinds of bindings (@, =, <, and &) can be made optional by adding ? to the expression.

It marks the parameter as optional. Read more: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile